# viewing mysql logs in django

Tags: mysql, django

Like on ruby on rails platform the server logs also show all queries(mysql) fired during the running of the app on local development machine.

But django running server doesn't shows them, Does there exist any app or plugins in django to view those or logging them in the log file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation to turn on the raw sql logging:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running

It works like this:

```
>>> from django.db import connection    
>>> connections.queries = []
>>> ..........execute a query............
>>> print connections.queries
```